# Sharing variables across multiple shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to summarize multiple shell scripts within one large shell script, such as this:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash script1.sh
bash script2.sh
bash script3.sh
```

All scripts share the same variables `var` and `var2`. I wanted to delete the variable definitions from the individual shell scripts and put it into the large shell script instead, so that when I change the value of the variables I only have to do that once.

However, when I do

```
#!/bin/sh
var1="1"
var2="2"
bash script1.sh
bash script2.sh
bash script3.sh
```

the variables are not recognised by the references `$var1` and `$var2` in the individual shell scripts.

Apologies if the question has been asked before, I am new to scripting in general and didn't know what to search for.

It would also be nice to know how I could loop over the scripts with multiple variable inputs, such as

```
var1="1 2 3 4 5"
var2="a b c d e"
for i in $var1;do for j in $var2;do
script1.sh
script2.sh
done;done
```

Comment: ...maybe put those variables in one shell snippet and "source" them in all scripts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you run scripts 1-3 inside your main script, they are each run inside their own sub-shell, which is why they don't recognise the variables defined in their parent shell. Use `export` to make variables available to sub-shells:

```
#!/bin/sh
export var1="1"
export var2="2"
bash script1.sh
bash script2.sh
bash script3.sh
```

An alternative (relevant for your second question) would be to pass the variables to the scripts as [positional parameters](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-shell-positional-parameters/):

```
#!/bin/sh
var1="1"
var2="2"
bash script1.sh "$var1" "$var2"
bash script2.sh "$var1" "$var2"
bash script3.sh "$var1" "$var2"
```

Inside scripts 1-3, these variables would then be available as `$1` and `$2` respectively.

Comment: Note that if you want changes made to the variables by any of the child scripts to persist then you should use "source" in place of "bash",

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

setup_env

```
var1="1"
var2="2"
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
bash script1.sh
bash script2.sh
bash script3.sh
```

script*.sh

```
source setup_env
...
```

Comment: To all the downvoters, may I know why? I can try to correct it.

Comment: sorry don't know much about your problem, but there are people on here who enjoy the power to downvote others where possible. They don't care to help.